# How to set Neo4J to restart automatically and to see the reson for crashing?

Tags: neo4j

I'm running Neo4J 2.0.1 (I know, it's a bit outdated, but it was a stable release a few months ago).

Sometimes my DB crashes on the server (Linux), so I was wondering if there's anything like forever.js app to restart neo4j when it crashed.

Also, where is it possible to see the reason for crashing? Logs, etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Restarting crashed processes is normally a task for your monitoring system (Icinga, Nagios, ...). They check for the availability of some service and take some action (like restart or escalation) upon failure.

However you should investigate the reason for the crashes. Upgrading Neo4j to a recent version (2.1.6 as of today) is rather simple, see reference manual. Also check out the release notes to see what has changed since 2.0.1 - the list is pretty long. So upgrade, check if the crashes still occur. If so analyze the root cause, check `data/graph.db/messages.log`.